# how to pass form value to another component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

> I want to show taxDetailsId in my child component Html page.
> But when click submit button.
> After click submit button then shows taxDetailsId in my child component Html page.

> Parent Component

```
export class OnlinePaymentComponent implements OnInit {
      HttpClient: any;
    
      paymentForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
        taxDetailsId: ['', [Validators.required]]
      });
    
      constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private router: Router,
      ) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {}
    
      submitForm(): void {
        if (!this.paymentForm.valid) {
          this.router.navigate(['/home/online-payment/error']);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
```

> Parent.Component.html

```
     <form [formGroup]="paymentForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
                <label>Tax Details Id</label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="taxDetailsId" placeholder="Tax Details Id" />
 <button>Pay Bill</button>
    <form>
```

> Child Component

```
export class OnlinePaymentErrorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

> Child.Component.html

```
  <div>
    <button [routerLink]="['/home/online-payment']" >Back Home</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: where do you instantiate the child component? If u don't instantiate it from the parent component (in html like `<OnlinePaymentErrorComponent />` it is not a parent and child component

Answer (score 0):

you can try this pattern `this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId }]);`

https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: This pattern doesn't work. Because I want to show formgroup value when press the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use angular @Input() decorator for it.

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'; 
export class ChileComponent {
   @Input() public taxDetailsId: number; 
}
```

**Child Component HTML**

```
enter code here
 <div>
   {{ taxDetailsId  }}
   <button [routerLink]="['/home/online-payment']" >Back Home</button>
 </div>
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<app-child-component [taxDetailsId]="taxDetailsId"> </app-child-component>
```

https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

Comment: This way I think works but doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass components around using Angular's `InjectionToken`.

First you start off by creating the token:

```
export const ONLINE_PAYMENT_REF = new InjectionToken<OnlinePaymentComponent>('OnlinePaymentComponent');
```

Next you add the token to one of the root components as a `provider`, in this case it is the `OnlinePaymentComponent`. This way everything that is a child of this component, and everything that is a child of those components, and so on; will  have a reference to the main parent that we create here:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'online-payment',
  template: `
    <online-payment-error></online-payment-error>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ONLINE_PAYMENT_REF,
      // Forwards the instance of OnlinePaymentComponent when injected into
      // the child components constructor.
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => OnlinePaymentComponent)
    }
  ]
})
export class OnlinePaymentComponent {
  message = 'I am the Online Payment Component';
}
```

Now that we have the main component setup, we can access it through the constructor of anything that is a child of `OnlinePaymentComponent` (no matter how deep it is).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'online-payment-error',
  template: `
  <h2>Child</h2>
  <strong>Parent Message:</strong> {{parentMessage}}
  `
})
export class OnlinePaymentErrorComponent implements OnInit {
  parentMessage = '';

  constructor(
    @Inject(ONLINE_PAYMENT_REF) private parent: OnlinePaymentComponent
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parentMessage = this.parent.message;
  }
}
```

When all is said and done, [you will see the following](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wenzaj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcompontents%2Fparent.component.ts):

[image: Result]

The pros of this method are that you don't have to bind values to the elements in the template, and if those components have components that need to reference the parent you wouldn't have to bind to those either. Since components look up the hierarchy till they find the first instance of the provider that we are looking for they will find the one in `OnlinePaymentComponent`.

This becomes very helpful when components get deeper and deeper into the parent component (say 5 levels deep), that means every time you would have to pass a reference to the template element 5 times, and if it changes or gets deeper you would have to update all the templates.

With this method we no longer need to update templates to pass data from one component to another component, we just request it in our constructor as seen in `OnlinePaymentErrorComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple ways:

1. Using query params (without routerLink).
2. Using Observables.

Using query params, you can use the router.navigate and pass the params you need (Id) along with the route.
eg: `this.route.navigate(['yourroute/route', { tId: variableWithId }])`

Using Observable, when you click on the button, use the same router navigate without params and pass the required data to an observable. On successful routing to the next page, get the resolved data from the observable.